# PyInstaller Hidden import not working "from module import sub-module"

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, pyinstaller

I have Python script that is compressed (I will not explain why) and the problem is that PyInstaller don't see import I am using, so I used `--hidden-import="Some Libraly"` and it works with python defaults any that has been installed with `pip`, doesn't.

PyInstaller Command:

```
C:/Example_path/temp_venv/Scripts/python.exe -m PyInstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --hidden-import="os" --hidden-import="json" --hidden-import="shutil" --hidden-import="base64" --hidden-import="psutil" --hidden-import="sqlite3" --hidden-import="zipfile" --hidden-import="requests" --hidden-import="subprocess" --hidden-import="threading" --hidden-import="PIL" --hidden-import="win32crypt" --hidden-import="re" --hidden-import="Crypto.Cipher" -i "NONE" --paths "C:/Example_path/temp_venv/Lib/site-packages" "C:/Example_path/2183952.py"
```

Import In Script: `from Crypto.Cipher import AES`
Error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'AES' from 'Crypto.Cipher' (C:\Users\No\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI73122\Crypto\Cipher\__init__.pyc)`

Comment: maybe you have to add also `--hidden-import="Crypto.Cipher.AES"` ? Or maybe it needs to add C/C++ library? Did you read documentation for [PyInstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)? Especially [Using Spec File](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html) and [When Things Go Wrong](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html)

Comment: @furas Thanks. it helped but there is another problem. There is import statment `from win32crypt import CryptUnprotectData`, but the package name (from pip) is `pypiwin32`. So far I tried `--collect-submodules`, but it didn't helped. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I have no idea. And I don't use Windows to check it.